# Is it a way to chaining chai.js's expects in nightwatch

Tags: javascript, testing, chai, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm want to use [chai.js](http://chaijs.com/) assertion bdd library with [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/).

**It's works**! My code looks like:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect

module.exports = {
  'Login' : function (browser) {
    var login = browser.page.login()
    login.expect.element('@login').to.not.be.enabled
    login.setValue('@email', 'some@some.com')
    login.setValue('@password', 'pass')
    login.expect.element('@login').to.be.enabled
    login.click('@login')
    login.end()
  }
}
```

**BUT**. Nightwatch provides pretty fluent interface for own methods which make you able to chain methods like `browser.setValue('...', '...').click('...').end()`.

**The question**: Can I achieve chaining of methods if I'm use chaijs?

Explanation, what I want:

```
module.exports = {
  'Login' : function (browser) {
    var login = browser.page.login()

    login.expect.element('@login').to.not.be.enabled
    .setValue('@email', 'some@some.com')
    .setValue('@password', 'pass')
    .expect.element('@login').to.be.enabled
    .click('@login')
    .end()
  }
}
```

Can I make my tests to looks like code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use multiple expects you have to do this:

```
module.exports = {
'Login' : function (browser) {
    var login = browser.page.login()

    login.expect.element('@login').to.not.be.enabled
    login
        .setValue('@email', 'some@some.com')
        .setValue('@password', 'pass')
        .expect.element('@login').to.be.enabled
    login    
        .click('@login')
    .end()
    }
}
```

This happens when you use .expect(...) in your test, or in custom functions within the page object, you have to use the browser/client/page object var again to start chaining again.